# ViewModel: how to display values from datatable in List View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created a viewmodel class for my custom page. I have a stored procedure which returns the DataTable(ORM tool). I cannot change this procedure. But I would like display the records from the stored procedure on View List. How can I display the values from the datatable in the List View? I appreciate any help.

Thanks,

```
public class CreateViewModel 
{
      [Required]
      public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
      [Required]
      [StringLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Details must be less than 250 characters")]     
      public string Details { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main way of doing it would be reading out the column values from each row of the datatable into the view model instance. This is regular DataTable access way. This should be done in your service layer called from your controller action.

If you can't change the stored proc, but are not tied to a DataTable then if you execute the SqlCommand to return a SqlReader. Then you can access the data with the following code (something like):

```
var list = new List<MyViewData>();
while(reader.Read())
{
 var model = new MyViewData();
 model.Property = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("ColumnName"));
 // .. etc..
 list.Add(model);
}

return list;
```

This accesses the recordset returned from the stored proc.

You can then set your view's model property as an IEnumerable then you can access each of the instances with a foreach over the model in the view.

Hope this helps.